# Extract number from dictionary in Javascript with Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, numbers, google-earth-engine

I started to learn javascript with Google Earth Engine and I have a problem :

```
var median_computed = Result.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  geometry: aoi.geometry(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
  });
```

I try to extract the median from a raster (Result) here but I can't extract the number from the dictionary after having used this function.

I used different method but I have the "Object.values is not a function" error when I try it. If I write median_computed[1] "undefined" is return and Object.keys return empty arrays.

However the dictionary median_computed is not empty since when I print it I can see :

"Object (1 property) VH: -1746.0890109890104".

The file I use is here : https://gofile.io/d/2PwXzo .

Comment: Try to log the object and add it to the question so we can have a better clue of what to to

Comment: It's done you can find it here : https://gofile.io/d/2PwXzo